# System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have a web site that I developed on Vista using Vb.net9.  It makes a connection to Oracle.  for the connection I use System.Data.OracleClient.  It works fine on my machine, and our test server, but it does not work on the production server.  We installed the Oracle Client 11 on the server.  The error is System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7

We've tried, making a console app that opens the connection, connection runs fine, opens, displays a message and all is well there.

Then we make a simple web form, put it in the directory of the program, just a button, opens the connection, try..catch, grabs error, same error.

The console app was running under an Administrator, web site running under iwam.  Is it possible that iwam has a different path?

Answer (score 59):

I've run into this error dozens of times:

**Cause**

Security permissions were not properly set when the Oracle client was installed on Windows with NTFS. The result of this is that content of the `ORACLE_HOME` directory is not visible to Authenticated Users on the machine; this causes an error while the `System.Data.OracleClient` is communicating with the Oracle Connectivity software from ASP.NET using Authenticated User privileges.

**Solution**

To fix the problem you have to give the Authenticated Users group privilege to the Oracle Home directory.

- Log on to Windows as a user with **Administrator** privileges.
- Start Windows Explorer and navigate to the `ORACLE_HOME` folder.
- Choose properties on the `ORACLE_HOME` folder.
- Click the *Security* tab of the *Properties* window.
- Click on *Authenticated Users* item in the *Name* list.
- Un-check the *Read and Execute* box in the *Permissions* list under the *Allow* column.
- Re-check the *Read and Execute* box under the *Allow* column.
- Click the *Advanced* button and in the *Permission Entries* verify that *Authenticated Users* are listed with permission: *Read & Execute*, and Apply To:  *This folder, subfolders and files*. If not, edit that line and make sure that *Apply To* drop-down box is set to *This folder, subfolders and files*. This should already be set properly but it is important that you verify it.
- Click the OK button until you close out all of the security properties windows. The cursor may present the hour glass for a few seconds as it applies the permissions you just changed to all subfolders and files.
- Reboot, to assure that the changes have taken effect.

Try your application again.

Comment: I've heard this puzzling trick before.  It's hard to believe that it works, but it does.

Comment: We had a variation of this--the user that the SS Reporting Services was running as was not part of "Authenticated Users", so we just had to ensure that particular user had access to the proper folders.  But all in all, this was good, helpful info!

Comment: thanks! i had this problem while deploying to production servers and searched around and found your answer. S.O. works!

Comment: Is this error appear only once? I have the same message when I try to import Oracle db by imp.exe, but it happens only once after installation of Oracle client 11

Comment: Over 2 years later, and you're still helping people out.  You just saved me several hours of headaches, I'm sure.  Thanks!!

Comment: Reboot was mandatory for me, maybe should re-word that last point as it sounds optional: Win2K8 R2 AntHill build server

Comment: Where will i find the `ORACLE_HOME` folder? When Oracle Database Client 12c Release 1 installs, it creates no folder called `ORACLE_HOME` in the selected install path. Nor is there an environment variable named `ORACLE_HOME`.

Comment: There is a much simpler solution. Open a command line window and enter `icacls /reset /T /C {Oracle installation folder}` - it does the same as all these clicks.

Answer (score 4):

The author of this post (now deleted post) suggests checking your `C:\Windows\System32` folder to make sure that the `oci.dll` exists there.  Copying in the file from the Oracle home directory solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 1:** It is possible for different users to have different path. But its not the likely problem here. There is more chance that the user that the iwam user doesn't have permission to the oracle client directory.

**Update 0:** Its suppose to work. Check for environment variable ( That are needed to find the oracle client and tnsnames.ora ). Also, Maybe you have a 32/64 bit issues. Also, consider using the Oracle Data Provider for .NET ( search for odp.net)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Client version 11 cannot connect to 8i databases. You will need a client in version 10 at most.

Answer (score 0):

When we first moved over to Vista with Oracle 10g, we experienced this issue when we installed the Oracle client on our Vista boxes, even when we were running with admin privileges during install.

Oracle brought out a new version of the 10g client (10.2.0.3) that was Vista compatible.

I do believe that this was after 11g was released, so it is possible that there is a 'Vista compatible' version for 11g also.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this: [dotConnect for Oracle](http://devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) (formerly known as OraDirect .NET)?

It can be configured to not require an Oracle Client at all.

We have been using this in both Windows Services and ASP.NET Web Services and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was some plugin in my Visual Studio started forcing my application into x64 64bit mode, so the Oracle driver wasn't being found as I had Oracle 32bit installed.

So if you are having this issue, try running Visual Studio in safemode (devenv /safemode).
I could find that it was looking in SYSWOW64 for the ic.dll file by using the ProcMon app by SysInternals/Microsoft.

Update: For me it was the Telerik JustTrace product that was causing the issue, it was probably hooking in and affecting the runtime version somehow to do tracing.

Update2: It's not just JustTrace causing an issue, JustMock is causing the same processor mode issue. JustMock is easier to fix though: Click JustMock-> Disable Profiler and then my web app's oracle driver runs in the correct CPU mode.  This might be fixed by Telerik in the future.