# Oracle Error using c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

The error is :
System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.

I'M using 8.1.7

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your Oracle database is 8.1.7 but your Oracle client is < 8.1.7? Do you use Oracle database 8.1.7?  8.1.7 is released in august 2000.

Comment: The client is 8.1.7 too, one more thing: when I connect with sqlplus it connects with no problem but using toad it doesnt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447983/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7)

Answer (score 1):

- check that you are using Oracle client 8.1.7 or above. Open CMD prompt and run sqlplus. Look at version information.
- Look at your PATH environment variable. Make sure that oracle client 8.1.7 or above is mentioned first (among multiple oracle clients), because AFAIK MS Oracle provider uses the first client mentioned in PATH.

Comment: in the PATH variable d:\orant\bin is first.

Answer (score 0):

Hard do say without more information.  I've had something similar happen to me when I had multiple clients installed.

Comment: when i try to open the connection it shows me that error, what kind of information do you need?

Comment: What user is the code running under?  Is it a web site?  I tend to think that JP is correct below in that it is a permissions issue, but I'd need more info to diagnose..

Comment: OK, its a console application that is running as a windows task, its running under an administrator user account.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a permissions issue.  Check out some of the [remedies here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=909975&tstart=0).  They might work for your version as well.