# System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have the same problem as the poser of this question:

[System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447983/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7)

I have made the changes to the security settings on the oracle folder, and have to wait for the server to reboot overnight.

My question is why is this reboot necessary?  I am getting the same error after making the changes without rebooting, so I don't doubt that it is.  Is there an alternative to rebooting the server, like `IISRESET`? (Although I wouldn't be allowed to run IISRESET during the day either)

Comment: Are you new to Oracle? This sort of thing is par for the course.

Comment: The thing is I'm guessing the answer is more related to Windows rather than Oracle.  Does Windows (or IIS) cache the security settings on the folder? As iisreset apparently resolves the problem, then is it the process that caches the security settings?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not an answer to your specific question, but for the record it is for this kind of reasons that I always favor [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html) :

- You don't have to install anything on the target machines (including dev boxes !). So no tricky manual setup and goat sacrificing.
- You can make sure that your application will run with the specific client you picked (version, x86/x64).
- You could even easily have multiple applications work with different client versions on the same computer.
- As a downside, it adds a significant weight to your application (~19Mb minimum), and you can't participate in distributed transactions.

If you still can switch, this is the way to go IMHO.  Check [What is the minimum client footprint required to connect C# to an Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602/what-is-the-minimum-client-footprint-required-to-connect-c-to-an-oracle-database/70901#70901) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Mac, it was too late, but it's definitely something I'll consider next time

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Server 2003 (hosting IIS6) it is enough to restart the service to bring environment changes and security changes into effect.

But this is done with iisreset. What is not allowed too.
**Thats a pity**, I see no other way as wait.

Comment: Thanks Christian, server reboot fixed the problem, the hours of anxiety I'll get over :)