# Error at the time of oracle add connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am using oracle 10g.

When I was connecting with oracle data base. I got this error

> System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.

Please help me

Comment: You need to install an Oracle client on that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .net Oracle library is a middleware between your application and the oracle client which has to be installed before you can start working with Oracle.

You might be interested [ODP.net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) as an alternative to System.Data.OracleClient as it is supported by Oracle and ships with a lightweight client (Instant client).

Comment: hi it resolved my error but i got another error

ORA-12154: TNS:could not be resolved the connect identifier specified

Comment: If you want to use TNS, you'll need to add a tnsnames.ora file in your network/config folder, otherwise you can use EZConnect which does not require any configuration

Comment: Is your connection string using tnsnames?

Comment: hi i debugged that error.
i missed data connection at ADO.net creation at step 4. i refered below article .

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm

help me pls

Answer (score 0):

This SO question/answer will hopefully cover your problem...

[System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447983/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7)

If not then: http://theniceweb.com/archives/64

Hope it helps...