# Change launch path of Visual Studio 2010 Web Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

How I can tell Visual Studio 2010 to launch built in web server from a different location. Is there a registry settings somewhere that I can modify or some how change the Debug -> Start Debugging menu item command?

From
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer20.exe

To
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer20.exe

Answer (score 3):

If you've facing the problem in connection with Oracle integration with ASP.NET in Windows 7 64 bits, then relax... XD

That's the solution (I'm using Visual Studio 2010 32 bits):

First of all, follow the steps here:

[System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447983/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7)

Then apply these steps:

1. Copy the directory of your webserver (typically in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0") to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0";
2. Open `cmd`, navigate to directory pasted in step 1 and start the web server (in my case "WebDev.WebServer40") pointing to the directory of your project (be careful, because this path cannot contain parenthesis, that causes the Oracle Bug 'ORA-06413: connection not open' as can be see described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/01/26/connectivity-issue-with-oracle-in-x64-environment-ora-12154-tns-could-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified.aspx));
3. If you want to debug your application, change the default URL to the URL of your started server in Visual Studio. In Solution Explorer go to your project > right click > properties > web > in "Servers" section select "Use Custom Web Server" and place the URL that your server are running on. After this, start debug and be happy =D

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still facing this issue in 2016 like me,
you can change **step1** of **Caique Lemos's** answer to:

```
mklink /J c:\ProgramsX86 "C:\Program Files (x86)"
```

And use `c:\ProgramsX86\...` for step2

Also, run as administrator can skip setting the folder permissions in the link above.