# How can I move Visual Studio development server to another folder that doesn't contain (x86)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Programs which path contains "(" cannot connect to Oracle. I reinstalled Visual Studio into C:\VS2010, so now Visual Studio's Server explorer connects to Oracle. But asp.net development server cannot connect because it is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0.
How can I move development server to another folder?

Comment: `Programs which path contains "(" cannot connect to Oracle` <== oh my; oh my oh my; that's just... I don't even; a quick google search seems to confirm, but that's just... wow.

Comment: It is ridiculous, but fact.
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_06413_connection_not_open.htm

Comment: I found the answer for setting custom development server for project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519070/change-launch-path-of-visual-studio-2010-web-server

Answer (score 3):

From the Oracle support docs:

> ### Subject: ORA-12154 or ORA-6413 Running 32-bit Oracle Software on 64-bit Windows OS
>
> **Applies to**: Oracle Net Services - Version: 8.1.7.0 to 10.2.0.1 Oracle
>   Data Provider for .NET - Version: 8.1.7.0 to 10.2.0.1 Oracle Objects
>   for OLE - Version: 8.1.7.0 to 10.2.0.1 Oracle Provider for OLE DB -
>   Version: 8.1.7.0 to 10.2.0.1 Oracle ODBC Driver - Version: 8.1.7.0 to
>   10.2.0.1 Microsoft Windows XP (64-bit Itanium) Microsoft Windows Server 2003 (64-bit Itanium) Microsoft Windows XP (64-bit AMD64 and
>   Intel EM64T) Microsoft Windows Server 2003 (64-bit AMD64 and Intel
>   EM64T)
>
> Symptoms You are attempting to connect to the Oracle database from a
>   Windows platform using one of the following programmatic interfaces
>
> ODBC OLEDB OO4O ODP.NET after installing 32-bit Oracle client software
>   on a 64-bit Windows operating system (OS) you receive one of the
>   following errors:
>
> ```
>  `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`
>
>     or
>
>  `ORA-6413: Connection not open.`
> ```
>
> Cause 64-bit Microsoft OS's install 32-bit applications into the following location "C:\Program Files (x86)..." rather than the typical location of "C:\Program Files..." This causes an existing networking bug to occur
>   where the networking layer is unable to parse program locations that
>   contain parenthesis in the path to the executable which is attempting
>   to connect to Oracle.
>
> The following bug has been filed to correct this behavior:
>
> > Bug 3807408 CANNOT EXTERNALLY AUTHENTICATE USER WITH QUOTE IN USERNAME
>
> ### Additional Information
>
> The reason you receive an ORA-12154 vs. an ORA-6413 is generally due
>   to which programmatic interface you have chosen to use to connect to
>   Oracle.
>
> The ORA-12154 is the typical error seen when connecting with
>   up-to-date interfaces using the latest version of the Oracle Call
>   Interface (OCI):
>
> Oracle ODBC Driver Oracle Provider for OLE DB Oracle Objects for OLE
>   Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) Microsoft's .NET Managed
>   Provider for Oracle The ORA-6413 is typical of using older interfaces
>   which make legacy API calls such as Oracle's OCI Version 7 API:
>
> Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle
>   Solution To resolve this problem try either of the following
>   solutions:
>
> ### SOLUTION 1:
>
> Use a version of the Oracle client AND database software that contains
>   the fix for Bug 3807408.  This fix requires that both the client and
>   database software be patched.
>
> Windows 32-bit
>
> - 9.2.0.7.0 Patch 6: Apply Patch 4928723 or later
> - 10.2.0.1.0 Patch 4: Apply Patch 4923768 or later
> - 10.2.0.2.0 Patch 5: Apply Patch 5383042 or later
> - 10.2.0.3.0: Apply Patch 5337014 or later
>
> Windows 64-bit AMD64 and INTEL EM64T
>
> - 10.2.0.1.0 Patch 4: Apply Patch 4923787 or later
> - 10.2.0.2.0 Patch 5: Apply Patch 5388871 or later
> - 10.2.0.3.0: Apply Patch 5337014 or later
>
> For all other versions on Windows please use SOLUTION 2 for now.
>
> ### SOLUTION 2:
>
> Find the location of the application that is generating the error. 
>   Check the path to this location and see if it contains any
>   parenthesis.  If so, you must relocate the application to a directory
>   without any parenthesis in the path.

Comment: So, apply the appropriate patch on both client and server. That seems like a safe idea in any case, since these patches have been around for quite some time.

Comment: Is there a patch for Oracle 10g 10.2.0.4 (my installed version)? Where can I download patches?

Comment: That version should be ok, but it must also be installed in the server. The fault somehow lies in the protocol.

Comment: If you have an account with oracle, more can be found at the following location: https://metalink.oracle.com/metalink/plsql/showdoc?db=Bug&id=3807408 you might have to ask your database support department to retrieve the right files.

Comment: And according to the docs here, installing the 11gR1 client instead of the 10g one, will also solve the issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/01/26/connectivity-issue-with-oracle-in-x64-environment-ora-12154-tns-could-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified.aspx