# System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater

Tags: .net, oracle

I had installed oracle 10g & trying to host my .Net Frame Work 2.0 web site but I am getting this message while trying to browse the site
System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447983/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm honest I've never tried installing a website on the same server as an oracle database but, whenever I've installed a website that needs access to an oracle backend then I've had to do the following:

- Install the relevant version of Oracle Client (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.htm
- Ensure my tnsnames.ora file has been correctly set up (http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora)

And that's about it. It should be reasonably straight forward. If you're still getting the same error then there's probably a problem with your ORACLE_HOME path set up in your registry. It could be that it's pointing to somewhere that it shouldn't be or, it's a permissions error. Take a look at this post for more info if installing the client doesn't work: [System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447983/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7)