# sql.data.oracleclient requires oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64

i am using VS 2008 vb.net Forms on 64 bit Windows and my application and db are working fine on my system. 
After i deploy the exe on the client systems, users are getting the following error

"sql.data.oracleclient requires oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater"

i tried to follow these instructions at [System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447983/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7), but the users client is from network drive and i can't set the permissions on the sub folder.

Is there any work around, or does the user have oracle folder on their local drive, if so where to find the local oracle client drive location ?

Comment: Yes, you have to install the oracle client on the machine.

Comment: user has other application vs2012 Forms.exe already working on their system without oracle client.