# System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software ver 8.1.7 or greater when creating report file (rdlc) in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, rdlc, odp.net

I'm having this problem when creating a report file / rdlc.
We already set the oracle_home folder permission and it's already working fine, we can get and fetch data already. The problem is when we're creating a report file. We're using 64-bit odp.net on a 64-bit workstation.

Also I found out that I can't locate odp.net provider on the list
[image]

I'm also having errors when using the .net provider:
[image]

Lastly, my vs stop working when i'm attaching a table on my rdlc:
[image]

any suggestions on how to make this work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: DO you have the Oracle_Home folder set up in the Environment variables?

Comment: Searched the environment variables and it's none

Comment: Go to Control Panel->System->View Advanced System setting, click Environment variables button. There you'll find User vriables and system variables. Select New in User variables, type Oracle_Home for variable name and the path to the Oracle_Home to the variable value. I can't promise that this'll solve the problem but this has been helpful in several cases.

Comment: Hi I added the environment variable in the user variables, copy the path in the registry where the oracle_home is pointed. restart the pc, but to no avail. Still can't see the odp provider in the list and vs crashes when i try to add a table/ add a datasource.

Comment: User variables only exist while the user is logged in.  Make sure you create a System variable instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447983/system-data-oracleclient-requires-oracle-client-software-version-8-1-7)