# Enterprise Library + Odp.Net BindParameterByName

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, odp.net

Anyone knows how to force odp.net bind parameters by name, using it with enterprise library? I know that exists `BindParameterByName` using `OracleCommand`, but I'm using odp.net with enterprise library and `DbCommand`.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046632/binding-query-parameters-by-name-with-odp-net) and [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2246928) posts can help.

First of them tell you to extend it by your self, like

public abstract class Database
{
    private readonly DbProviderFactory factory;

```
protected Database(DbProviderFactory factory)
{
    this.factory = factory;
}

public virtual DbCommand CreateCommand(String commandText)
{
    return CreateCommand(CommandType.Text, commandText);
}

public virtual DbCommand CreateCommand(CommandType commandType, String commandText)
{
    DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = commandType;
    command.Text = commandText;
    return command;
}

public virtual void BindParametersByName(DbCommand command)
{

}
```

}
And choose to create an Oracle specific implementation that overrides default command creation or provides the option to bind parameters by name.

public class OracleDatabase : Database
{
    public OracleDatabase()
        : base(OracleClientFactory.Instance)
    {

```
}

public override DbCommand CreateCommand(CommandType commandType, String commandText)
{
    DbCommand command = base.CreateCommand(commandType, commandText);
    BindParametersByName(command);
    return command;
}

public override void BindParametersByName(DbCommand command)
{
    ((OracleCommand)command).BindByName = true;
}
```

}