# Can I instruct EF DbContext to use "real" parameter names?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm using an EF (6, if it matters) `DbContext` subclass, and trying to implement an interceptor to set or update auditing data when an entity is written to the database.

My interceptor class:

```
public class EntitySaveInterceptor : BaseDbCommandInterceptor
{
    private const string CreatedAt = "@CreatedAt";
    private const string ModifiedAt = "@ModifiedAt";

    //called for update, but not insert
    public override void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        var parameters = command.Parameters
            .OfType<DbParameter>()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.ParameterName, p => p);
        if (parameters.ContainsKey(ModifiedAt))
        {
            parameters[ModifiedAt].Value = SystemTime.UtcNow();
        }
    }

    //called for insert
    public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        var parameters = command.Parameters
            .OfType<DbParameter>()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.ParameterName, p => p);
        if (parameters.ContainsKey(CreatedAt))
        {
            parameters[CreatedAt].Value = SystemTime.UtcNow();
        }
        if (parameters.ContainsKey(ModifiedAt))
        {
            parameters[ModifiedAt].Value = SystemTime.UtcNow();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is that these commands don't contain `"@CreatedAt"` or `"@ModifiedAt"` parameters. Instead, the value for the `CreatedAt` column is passed in a parameter named `@3` (indicating the zero-indexed position in the values list), and the value for the `ModifiedAt` column (a `DateTime?` value) is hard-coded as `NULL` in the generated SQL when its value is `null`.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196449/182654), but a cursory examination of [the `SqlCommand` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) reveals that `BindByName` is an ODP.Net specific concept.

It's obvious that I can inspect the command text at this point, match the column names in the `INSERT` statement with the parameter names and `NULL`s in the `VALUES` clause, and update the `command.Parameters` collection to match the new SQL.  But, if possible, I'd prefer to have my `DbContext` use parameter names that match up with the column names.

So - can I instruct my `DbContext`, or something upon which it relies, to use parameter names based on property or column names when it is creating `DbCommand` objects?

Comment: Do you really care about the *parameters names* or do you want *set or update auditing data when an entity is written to the database.*  The second can be done without the first.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'd much prefer to get the parameter names, because then I can do whatever.  The auditing data is simply the first use case.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to override `DbContext.SaveChanges` and set property values there.  The below is an example of a type-agnostic (though not necessarily the most efficient) application of the current date/time to any added entity with a `CreatedAt` property:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach( var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries() )
        {
            if( entry.State == EntityState.Added && 
                entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains( "CreatedAt" ) )
            {
                entry.CurrentValues[ "CreatedAt" ] = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. +1