# <mimer-sql> Binding query parameters by name with Mimer SQL Data Provider

Tags: parameters, binding, mimer-sql

Currently only [A] has been tested. Is [B] possible?

[A]:

```
SELECT code, country, currency_code FROM countries
WHERE currency_code = ? AND code = ?
```

[B]:

```
SELECT code, country, currency_code FROM countries
WHERE currency_code = :currency_code AND code = :code
```

---

Oracle has the following method.

```
  using var command = new OracleCommand(query, connection);

  command.BindByName = true;
```

( [Binding query parameters by name with ODP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046632/binding-query-parameters-by-name-with-odp-net) )

Comment: Either way should work. The major difference is that version [B] can't pass null values. (To add null value capability, you should do something like :currency_code :indicator.)

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for editing my article beautifully. As you said, [B] also works. However, it does not work by parameter names, but when the order of parameters you add to [the Command] matches. If you change the parameter addition order, [B] will not work.

Comment: Which programming environment are you using?

Comment: C#, Visual Studio 2022 and MimerSQL.Data.Provider( https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimerSQL.Data.Provider/ ).

Comment: You can also try ordering the parameters, like `WHERE currency_code = :2 AND code = :1` if you want to provide code value first.

Comment: My concern is binding query parameters to SQL by name.