# How to write a .Net application that works with both SqlServer and Oracle (now that System.Data.OracleClient is deprecated)

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

see also [System.Data.OracleClient namespace discontinued?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004484/system-data-oracleclient-namespace-discontinued)

(Firstly don’t panic yet, System.Data.OracleClient is not being removed by Microsoft yet, however it is not in the client version of .net 4)

This use to be possible by using System.Data.OracleClient, [however Microsoft has decided to deprecate OracleClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage).  (OracleClient is the ADO.NET provider for Oracle developed by Microsoft and ships as a part of the .NET Framework.)

You could use ODP.Net, however do you wish your Sql Server customers to have to install ODP.Net?  (Do you wish any of your customers to have to install Oracle software?)

[DataDirect](http://www.datadirect.com/products/net/index.ssp) is not an option as it costs an arm and a leg; it may just about be affordable if you need to connect a single server to a mainframe.  However it is not an option to expect all customers to buy it.

Moving form C# to Java is not a good option, as I am a C# programmer and wish to be able to earn a living!

Like most ISVs that have to support multiple RDBMS we only need a solution that allows us to use the small subset of Oracle that is the same as SqlServer.  Therefore System.Data.OracleClient was powerful enough for us.

(Maybe we should just start storing all data in flat files, so that customer’s DBA stop trying to tell us how to write software.  Oracle DBAs are the worse!)

---

My real question is how can I write .NET software that talks to Oracle that is us pain free to installed as .NET software that talks to SqlServer.  Having to use ODP.NET just makes the oracle client install yet more painful, with yet more to go wrong.

If I was using JAVA I could just use JDBC type 4 drivers.  Microsoft provides one for SqlServer and Oracle provides one for Oracle.  However it seems that Oracle wishes to make .Net usage as hard as possible and Microsoft wishes to make Oracle usage as hard as possible.

---

So far the **best option** looks like [devArt's dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/).

*However I am starting to question weather .NET is a good development system for ISV, as sooner or later you always get a customer that demands oracle support.    In the Java world they seem to have this problem solved.*

---

It looks like Oracle may be about to bring out a senible Fully Managed ADO.NET provider themselfs it may even be easy to install! see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/ow2010-whatsnew-dotnet-177300.pdf) that claims Beta – 2011, Production – End of 2011.

Comment: I'd vote this question up 50 times if I could. Oracle's client software is a PITA. .NET applications should be able to connect to Oracle servers without having to install proprietary client software first (MySql doesn't need one, why would Oracle?)

Comment: Terrible terrible decision. Perhaps they should stop supporting IE because there are 3rd party alternatives available. What a stupid reason. </rant>

Comment: Why don't you just abstract away your db Connections using an ORM like NHibernate or role your own abstraction using the The Provider Factory Pattern, then you can use whatever DB you want without having to change your code

Comment: Bod The Janitor -> A ORM or our own abstraction layer will still have to sit on top of something that talked to Oracle.

Comment: But you only need to include Oracle where they are using Oracle

Comment: Is your question really, "How do I get ODP.NET on my client's and developers' machines?" Because it seems you're good on the ADO.NET side. And I find this odd, because even System.Data.OracleClient required an installation to work with many Oracle configurations.

Comment: @ajmastrean. I think it is. Let the customer install the Oracle client + odp.net (this is one installation).

Comment: Oracle has announced that sometime in 2011 they will release a fully managed version of the ODP.NET provider (aka thin client). When that happens there will be no dependency by ODP.NET on any other files and this headache will go away.

Comment: @Christian, please add an answer including links to the info of the managed version of the ODP.NET so I can upvote it

Comment: @Ian, here's a few links: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/ow2010-whatsnew-dotnet-177300.pdf http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=18357:46

Comment: Fully managed ODP.NET is available in beta now. It is less than 10 MB in size and doesn't have dependencies on any other files: EDIT:   As of this writing this beta is available here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbeta-1696432.html  (This link will break once it goes production)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: The fully managed ODP.NET is now available in production. It is very small (less than 10MB) and is not dependent on other files.  You can obtain it here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Original answer:

One way to *easily* ensure that the required Oracle client side software (including ODP.NET) is always available on the deployment machine is to embed it with your application. ODP.NET has gotten a *lot* easier to embed now that XCOPY ODP.NET is available. You can download it from this link:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html

With XCOPY ODP.NET,  all you need to do when you deploy your application  is the following:

1) Copy your application to the target machine

2) Run "install.bat" which copies a couple of Oracle DLL's to the target machine (including ODP.NET and the Oracle client side (OCI) software)

3) Run "configure.bat", which does a "gacutil" and updates the registry of the target machine

4) Provide your application with connect string  information. You can use the EZCONNECT connect string ("hostname@servicename")  or you (or your customer) can share preexisting sqlnet configurations by setting the TNS_ADMIN registry entry or environment variable to point to another Oracle home that has sqlnet connect aliases already configured.

That's it! It is really that simple.

I hope you will take a good look at ODP.NET XCOPY in the link above to see for yourself how easy it is these days to embed ODP.NET with your app.

---

Additional notes:

If you choose not to embed ODP.NET with your application, in both the case of Microsoft OracleClient and in the case of ODP.NET, there needs to be additional Oracle client side (OCI) software installed on any deployment machine. The only difference between the two cases is that when you are using ODP.NET,  it also needs to exist on the deployment machine. The good news is that a typical Oracle install on your customer machine will include ODP.NET already.

Now, if your target machine already has ODP.NET installed you don't need to do anything else. You just need to distribute your application. If you do need to install ODP.NET using the standard installer, you can also download it from the link provided above. The standard ODP.NET install only takes a few minutes and configures everything for you.

And again, you can use EZConnect connect strings to make networking configuration a piece of  cake, or use the TNS_ADMIN registry entry or environment variable to take advantage of pre-existing connect aliases that your customer is already used to using.

Hope this helps,

Christian Shay

Oracle

Feel free to provide your feedback on this and other future features at our feature request website:
http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=18357:46

Comment: +1 for the announcement of a fully managed ODP.NET. Didn't know that was coming!

Comment: you can always simply copy the 6MB Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll and don't worry about the rest :)

Comment: That nuget package was not put there by Oracle. Just a fyi.

Comment: *"xcopy deployment"*. They keep using that word. [I do not think it means what they think it means](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326355#bookmark-2). Also, Oracle now does have their own [official nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/).

Comment: Hi Ian, for what it is worth, the later versions of unmanaged ODP.NET do not require registry entries, GAC installs, or global config file entries. So the deployments can be as simple as file copies (xcopy). Things can be trickier when working with things like provider factories which have machine.config entries but you can still do the config file entries yourself and simply copy files.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at alternate Oracle providers like [devArt's dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/)? This driver, as an example, is 100% managed code, supports many advanced Oracle features, provides Entity Framework support (that will come some day in ODP.NET, I'm sure).

There are a bunch of other features (like ASP.NET provider model support) that we didn't get until the ODP.NET 11g release. Pretty liberal licensing and reasonably priced. Also comes with it's own profiler, if I remember correctly.

In [their tests](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/performance.html), performs favorably compared to ODP.NET. I'd love to point you to something open source but, in my experience, once you've bought into Oracle as a database, you've already accepted the fact that you'll be laying down some cash for your database-related tooling.

Comment: Thanks I will look at devArt's dotConnect, the problem is we have not "bought into Oracle" but our sales poeple don't no how to say no to customers that have DBAs with a Oracle only policy. I am connerned however about depending on a 3rd party for data access, e.g. will devArts still be surporting dotConnect in 20 years times?

Comment: I'm looking at devArt's provider but fully understand the concern. Most folks aren't going to deviate far from ODP.NET. Unfortunately then for the app folks, they only get innovation and ease of use at the rate at which Oracle is willing to provide it.

Comment: Do you really expect devArt to be supporting their provider in 20 years when Microsoft has dropped support for their provider in less than half that time? Products come and go, you can't depend on any of them to be around tomorrow let alone 20 years from now.

You just have to use the best tools available at the time and hope they'll be there tomorrow. I've used devArt drivers before, they were very good.

Comment: Fully managed ODP.NET is available in beta now. It is less than 10 MB in size and doesn't have dependencies on any other files: EDIT:   As of this writing this beta is available here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbeta-1696432.html  (This link will break once it goes production)

Answer (score 3):

There's a big difference between being deprecated and being removed.

If you're just using the subset of functionality that is common to both SQL Server and Oracle, then you should be fine moving through to ASP.Net 4.0 and continuing to program how you do currently.

Using something like [EntitySpaces](http://www.entityspaces.net), would let you be relatively provider-agnostic. (it uses OracleClient in it's DAL)

Completely agree with Philippe about Oracle's client software being a pain. I've lost track of the number of times I've installed it and hated the experience. Give me MySQL, SQLServer or even Access in preference.

(Actually, I take back the Access comment) :-)

Comment: +1 for the Oracle client pain comment. It's the only thing I've ever installed that made me think the authors had some sort of vendetta against me personally.

Comment: It is not in the client profile of .net 4, so using  System.Data.OracleClient will make it a lot harder to use .net 4 on cleint machines as you have to get your users to do a larger install of .net

Answer (score 3):

Use the "The Provider Factory Pattern" which is basically using a factory to give a data provider that is completely abstracted away from the database request methods that uses it  here is a [blogpost](http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2009/05/provider-factory-pattern.html) with some sample code that shows how to do this also [Jean-Paul Boodhoo on Demystifying Design Patterns](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=63) Part 1 on dnrtv.com shows how to as well.

This is some very cool stuff basically you have a factory that provides a methods for getting a connection

```
public IDbConnection GetConnection()
{
     IDbConnection connection =  _frameworkDBProviderFactory.CreateConnection();
     connection.ConnectionString = _authenticationSettings.ConnectionString;            
     return connection;
}
```

though an interface so you can call any type of Database who's connection object implements the IDbConnection interface (SQLServer, MySQL, Oracle, etc.) and it just works.

By abstracting away what DB your using you can even swap them out at run time and your application will never know, it doesn't need to so to connection to an Orical DB, download the [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html), same thing with [mysql connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) both implement IDbConnection, and write your code against the abstracted connection.

Comment: Yes, all good coding, but this does not help with pain of having to get customers to install ODP.NET.  The coding is the easy bit, it's the on going surport of customers that is hard...

Comment: So it's not a programming related question then?

Comment: By my own experience, you cannot go very far on the generic road with ODP .NET : there is of course the BindByName idiocy (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046632/binding-query-parameters-by-name-with-odp-net. Granted, it can be circumvented in a generic way...), beware you HAVE to specify the parameter length for CHAR datatypes, and know that you cannot rely on the OracleCommandBuilder implementation (cf. http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1458797&#1458797). For instance.

Comment: Let the customer install opd.net + Oracle client. After this has beeen done you can use this providerfactory in your app. It will use the needed oracle dll's from the GAC.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have suggested you could consider using the Provider pattern and Oracle's ODP.NET.

Comment: How does this advoid the problems with installing ODP.NET?

Comment: If you're not using the Oracle code you don't need to install the ODP.NET client.

Comment: You need an Oracle Home installed to use System.Data.OracleClient with any configuration fancier than the default (like LDAP name resolution). If your client is an Oracle shop, they'll install ODP.NET.

Comment: "If your client is an Oracle shop, they'll install ODP.NET"  I wish it was that simple.  Often the Oracle DBA is unwilling to touch a windows machine.  Anyway our clients are NOT the IT department, so it depends on how well our clients get on with their IT departments.

(Our developers and testing have still got to get machine setup that can talk to oracle to write the software)

Comment: [Re: developers] The ODP.NET install (as of ODAC 10.2) requires 1 item, "ODP for .NET 2.0".
[Re: client] I would contact Oracle about silent or preconfigured installations.

Comment: @ajmastrean- That's a good point . @Ian Ringrose- see here- http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/manage.1012/b16227/oui4_response_files.htm

Answer (score 2):

Being database independent is a very hard job because there are a lot of specific things (bind variable naming, object quotation, ...). Use a library like [NHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.org) which puts a layer between your application and the real database.

If you have to connect to both databases, than it's a question of deployment.
If you connect to oracle (using System.Data.OracleClient or Oracle.DataAccess.Client) you need oracle client software installed on your machine. The database provider deployed with framework is not enough to connect to an oracle database.

If you connect to oracle, you have to install software from oracle. If you fear the deprecation, than install and use ODP.Net. There are some [differences](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/dotnet/msoc/index.html) between the 2 oracle database provider.

For better deployment oracle introduced the concept of [instant client](http://search.oracle.com/search/search?default=true&keyword=instant+client&start=1&nodeid=&fid=&showSimilarDoc=true&group=Oracle+Technology+Network). This client can deployed using xcopy deployment. Sine oracle 11 the instant client can be bundled with ODP.Net.

The installation of ODP.Net is described in the post of Christian Shay.

The Oracle.DataAccess assembly must not be in die global assembly cache. Put it in your bin directory. The instant client used by Oracle.DataAccess must not be in a different directory on your client machine. Put it in your bin directory. The [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technology/docs/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) describes how to configure your application to find a instant client.

Answer (score 1):

Would using ODBC for both be feasible?

Comment: maybe, however what if the user does not have admin rights on the PC etc?  E.g the application has to install/run without changing the registor

Answer (score 1):

Aren't people supposed to be using the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) now? [See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle)

Comment: According to Microsoft, yes.  Of course many of us want to make our own decisions...

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not invoke an ODP.Net object, you don't need to install ODP if you only access SQL Server.

Comment: Interesting, not that simple as if a class is invoked that has a field that is a ODP class it will give a problem.  But by using interface should be able to get round that.

Comment: ODP.NET fully implements the ADO.NET 2.0 standards (DbProviderFactory, etc) and I have successfully used -only- the base classes (DbConnection, DbCommand, etc) for Oracle data access at a large company (read: strange Oracle configurations).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that ODBC can still use both SQL Server and Oracle with some transparency, so I would take a look at using ADO.Net with the ODBC provider.  It won't give you all of the performance or features that SqlClient or OracleClient would, but it should be pretty close to the same code for Oracle or SQL Server.

Comment: Indeed.  Additionally, to get ODBC working, you can use Oracle's InstantClient libraries instead of installing the bulky Oracle Client software.  InstantClient installation is 26MB of dlls, and you just need to include their location in your PATH variable.  In our applications, we actually make the changes to the PATH variable inside our application at startup, so the installation is invisible to the rest of the system  - no more worries about making sure the proper version of Oracle Client is installed, or stepping on existing installations.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [SubSonic 3.0](http://www.subsonicproject.com/)! I have it run my SQLServer, MySQL and SQLite based application and user can switch between these 3 at runtime!

Comment: how this this advoid having to install ODP.NET?  As far as I know SubSonic sits on top of ODP.NET

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you cannot simply deploy the ODP.NET data provider DLL. Oracle requires a Home installation for anything more than the default configuration (for instance, we use LDAP name resolution, requiring an LDAP.ora file in a special Home path).

However, ODP.NET implements the ADO.NET 2.0 standards just fine (DbProviderFactory, etc). And I have programmed against the base classes (DbConnection, DbCommand, etc) without any need for the specific classes for some time at my company.

My suggestion for making this data access work is to use/follow the guidance in the [Entlib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx) or use [NHibernate](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html).

If you have a logistics or IT problem installing ODP.NET or getting it to your customer/client, I suggest you talk to your IT people and Oracle about solutions for that.

Answer (score 0):

The customer should install odp.net and the Oracle client on there machines. You should not deploy it. Your application will find the needed Oracle dll's in the GAC.