# Deploying ODP.NET WPF application

Tags: wpf, oracle, deployment, odp.net

**Background:** I developed a small **.NET 3.5 WPF** application that connects to an **Oracle 9i** database.  Thinking that the ODP.NET version had to match the database, I downloaded and used an [older version][1] (9i, release 2, to be more specific) of the Oracle Data Access tools.

I'm basically done the application now and need to deploy it.  Then I looked at the deployment story for ODP.NET, thinking it would be included as a prerequisite by ClickOnce and I wouldn't have to do anything.  **Lesson. Learned.**

Everything I've read about deployment for ODP.NET talks about using XCOPY with a newer version of the Oracle tools than what I have used to this point.  Not much is actually said about 9i in the documentation I've read to this point.

So what should I do?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar post where the answer was to change to use a 3rd party library:

[ODP.NET and ClickOnce possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193112/odp-net-and-clickonce-possible)

I think you area in trouble as changing libraries may involve you doing a full retest of your application - this may of course be easier done than said if it is a small app or you have good automated test coverage. Of course it depends how many computers you are deploying to. Personally I would be more inclined to stick with oracle odp and move to the latest version. If you deploy odp "the hard way" you still get the benefit of click once for future redeployments.

Comment: Looks like I am in trouble, what a pain ODP.NET is.