# Is it possible to connect Oracle DB without Oracle Client in .Net framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, oracle

As I understand ODP.Net support .NET Framework 4.6.2 and 4.7,
Please let me know is there any other way to connect Oracle DB from my existing application which still using .net framework 2.0 ?

Type: Client / Server application 
DB :  In different dedicated seperated Server 
Reason to change : to deploy remotely via ClickOnce deplyoment

Currently I have to install Oracle client before my application installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. In .NET framework 2.0 you have to use the unmanaged ODP.NET provider 2.x, this requires an Oracle Client.

The ODP.NET **Managed driver** which does not require any further installation of an Oracle Client is available only for .NET framework 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand ODP.Net support .NET Framework 4.6.2 and 4.7, Please let me know is there any other way to connect Oracle DB from my existing application which still using .net framework 2.0 ?

Oracle still offers a ODP.Net library for .NET 2, you can download it from their web site (both 32 bit and 64 bit ODAC downloads)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Edit: it seems like the .Net 2.0 driver is unmanaged and requires oracle client libraries to work. There is a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193112/odp-net-and-clickonce-possible) regarding the deployment of Oracle Client via ClickOnce, which explains the process in some detail. You essentially need to compile your application for the platform(s) you want to support and make sure the oracle client libraries are included in the deployment package. The [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193112/odp-net-and-clickonce-possible) is a bit older and refers to oracle client 11, so some of the libraries the unmanaged driver depends on will have changed.

Comment: Does it require to install Oracle client when I deploy on client PC ?

Comment: @Louisplh sorry, it seems you're right, Oracle does seem to have changed their driver deployment recently. Yes, you'll need to deploy the oracle client with your application if you want to use the ODP.Net driver in .Net 2. But it seems you can deploy the client with ClickOnce: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193112/odp-net-and-clickonce-possible