# Support for Enterprise Library 4.1 connecting to Oracle

Tags: oracle, enterprise-library

I have just read that MS is discontinuing the System.Data.OracleClient driver [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004484/system-data-oracleclient-namespace-discontinued). Does Enterprise Library 4.1 for Oracle use this driver and if so does that mean that it won't work or be supported in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, entlib 4.1, and every other version use System.Data.OracleClient. I don't know I'd the framework team plans to actually remove that code from the platform or just not work on it anymore. For entlib 4.1, there's an open-source Oracle database class that uses Oracle's ODP.NET driver. It's available from http://entlibcontrib.complex.com.

Answer (score 0):

Use Enterprise Library 5 and download the last release from ODP.NET.

Then follow [this tutorial](http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/enterprise-library-5-with-odp-net/).