# how to connect Oracle in vb.net 2005?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, oracle10g

I'm a newbie to connect Oracle 10g using vb.net in MS Visual 2005. Please share me in coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific in your question because no one will write your project for you.

There are tons of resources on line to help you:

[Using Oracle with VB.NET](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/ado/oracle.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with being married to Oracle, a native driver is fastest.  You tagged VS2005 so I assume you are deploying to .NET Framework 2.0.  Our shop uses [System.Data.OracleClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient(v=VS.80).aspx) and it works fine (you will need the Oracle client installed on the target machine).  This namespace, however, [has been deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx) in the 4.0 framework release.  The preferred way forward (which I've not tried yet) is either [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085703.html) or another 3rd-party driver.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004484/system-data-oracleclient-namespace-discontinued) details some of the alternatives.