# Oracle and ADO.NET (The types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated.)

Tags: .net, sql, oracle

I'm writing a application, where I also work with ADO.NET:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
```

Code example:

```
try{
       OracleConnection myOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
       myOracleConnection.Open();
       OracleCommand command = myOracleConnection.CreateCommand();
       ...
   }
```

It works but I got warnings:

```
Warning 3   'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand' is obsolete: 'OracleCommand has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260'
```

Whats other options do I have? "*Microsoft recommends that you use a third-party Oracle provider.*" --

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Data.OracleClient namespace discontinued?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004484/system-data-oracleclient-namespace-discontinued)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using ODP.NET ([Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html))

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET) features optimized ADO.NET
>   data access to the Oracle database. ODP.NET allows developers to take
>   advantage of advanced Oracle database functionality, including Real
>   Application Clusters, XML DB, and advanced security. The data provider
>   can be used with the latest .NET Framework 4 version.
>
> ODP.NET makes using Oracle from .NET more flexible, faster, and more
>   stable. ODP.NET includes many features not available from other .NET
>   drivers, including a native XML data type, self-tuning, RAC-optimized
>   connection pooling, promotable transactions, and Advanced Queuing.

- [ODP.NET for Microsoft OracleClient Developers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085703.html)
- [Microsoft OracleClient to ODP.NET Application Migration](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/msoc-migration-337643.html)

Comment: is that a DLL? Does the Syntax of Code change?

Comment: @eMi: yes, its a DLL. there are some minor differences. (I remember I had to set the `BindByName` property to true)

Comment: I use now ODP.NET, but cannot establish a Connection, because ConnectionString seems to be wrong. but its exactly the same. :(

Comment: Got it exactly, like in the Examples... thats the Exception: `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`