# oracle without installing the data provider

Tags: .net, oracle, powershell, oracle10g

I am creating a script that retrieves data from a local oracle db. As of now I have the oracle data provider for .net installed. However, this is a big file and a long installation process. Is there a way to deploy a software that utilizes the System.Data.OracleClient without having to install the data provider?

Answer (score 3):

Instant Client is the answer... see [this Question for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602/what-is-the-minimum-client-footprint-required-to-connect-c-to-an-oracle-database).  I can only vouch for it working with ODP.Net though.

Comment: I have used the Instant Client with just plain vanilla ADO.NET and the included Oracle driver in .NET 1.1 and later. In fact, we use it on a production server here for a very small ASP.NET web services site. Just remember to add the directory that contains the Oracle DLLs to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Instant Client is still a large install