# What do I need to do to get a Mono application to talk to oracle?

Tags: .net, oracle, mono

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) is an open source version of the .net framework, having a quick look at it's website it claims to have Linq-to-Oracle support.  How hard is this to get working, e.g. does oracle software need to be installed on the client machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://www.mono-project.com/Oracle) suggests that Oracle client is required - you could try the [EZ Connect approach](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT) as well.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, yes. You need the Oracle client installed and configured properly (TNS, etc) on the server to connect to the database, whether you're using Mono or not.
I have no experience with Mono, but I doubt they can get past that issue (and why should they?).

Comment: I was hoping they did what java did and just talked over TCP to the Oracle server

Answer (score 1):

As [Sathya said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265477/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-a-mono-application-to-talk-to-oracle/1268253#1268253), an Oracle client is needed with the default Mono provider.

Check the procedure described in [What is the minimum client footprint required to connect C# to an Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602/what-is-the-minimum-client-footprint-required-to-connect-c-to-an-oracle-database/70901#70901). It has been made for .NET on Windows. It will be exactly the same for Mono, and can easily be adapted for Linux.

Note that commercial providers exist for .NET that do not require an Oracle client. You could check out their support of Mono (you can [find more here](http://www.sqlsummit.com/DataProv.htm)) :

- [DataDirect ADO.NET Data Provider for Oracle](http://www.datadirect.com/products/net/net%5Ffor%5Foracle/index.ssp).
- [dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/).