# OracleClient + TNSless connection with .NET

Tags: .net, oracle, database-connection, ora-12514

We are using System.Data.OracleClient and the abstract base classes DbConnection, DbCommand (etc) to connect to Oracle.

The connection works fine in our development stages.  During staging we encounter the error ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.

Our goal was to connect without a TNS entry, and providing all the relevant information in the connection string (www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#19)

I can confirm that SQL plus will connect to the desired schema from the staging server (the listener is listening).  The TNS entry hooked into SQLPlus matches all the credentials of the query string being built.

```
SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;
```

Is there an installation on the server we missed?  Something we can tweak?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A SID is not a Service Name.  A service name is usually a fully qualified database name, while a SID is a short identifier.

A service name might be dbname.company.com while your SID is dbname.  An instance can actually have several service names associated with it, but only one SID.

Change your SERVICE_NAME to SID in your connect string, or specify your service name for the SERVICE_NAME option.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I banged my head against many a wall before I grasped the difference.

Comment: The SID is the physical instance name on a system, corresponding to the operating system service running the instance. The SERVICE name is a logical name for the database. It's more flexible than SID, because another instance can be substituted transparently to the client by simply making the service name of the new instance the same as the old one. It can also be used in load balancing, as you can have multiple instances with the same service name. The default service name for an instance is the instance name concatenated with a dot and the db_domain.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, I had the same issue until I switched to using the Oracle providers and OracleDbConnection and OracleDbCommand. The generic ones don't always instantiate the correct provider in all cases.

Comment: Hmm... well I do instantiate the OracleDbConnection specifically.  The handle I use is the base class, so I'm not sure why that would be an issue.  DbConnection conn = new OracleConnection(str);

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft deprecated the `System.Data.OracleClient`.
See [this post](http://blogs.oracle.com/databaseinsider/2009/07/microsoft_deprecates_systemdataoracleclient_net_developers_for_oracle_should_migrate_to_oracle_data_provider_for_net.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your Oracle client is in version 10+, you could also use [EZCONNECT](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT) (which stands for [Easy Connect naming method](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306%5F01/network.102/b14212/naming.htm#ABC524382SRI12)). Your connection string would then look like this :

```
"Data Source=MyHost:MyPort/MyServiceName;User ID=myUserName;Password=myPassword"
```

Combined with [Oracle Instant Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602/what-is-the-minimum-client-footprint-required-to-connect-c-to-an-oracle-database/70901#70901), it makes the use of Oracle feel almost professional !...