# How can I deploy a .NET application that uses ODAC without installing the whole component to the user?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, deployment, odac

I have written a C# application that connects to an Oracle 10g database. Using Oracle Data Access Component 11.2 "ODAC", it works perfectly on my machine.

And now I want to deploy the application and install it in another "clean machine" that has the .NET Framework only! And I don't want to install the whole ODAC component to the user!

How could I do that? I have tried to include all the necessary DLL files to my bin folder, like:

- oci.dll
- ociw32.dll
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll
- orannzsbb11.dll
- oraocci11.dll
- oraociicus11.dll
- OraOps11w.dll
- msvcr71.dll

But still it didn't work. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your concern is about having to install the Oracle client in addition to the ~50 MB ODAC install or just the standalone ODAC.

If the concern is about having to install the Oracle client and the ODAC, you can use the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html)?  That's the smallest footprint method for installing the Oracle client.  You'll also need the ODAC xcopy supplement.

If your concern is just the ODAC install, I don't think there is a smaller footprint available.

Comment: correct me if iam wrong .. i have to install the oracle instant client in all machines that will run my application ?? and what do you mean by the ODAC XCopy supplement ??  do you mean the dll's that i mentioned before ??  thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Correct.  The instant client would need to be installed on every client machine.  But the instant client is designed to be bundled with applications and is made up of just a handful of DLLs.  The ODAC Xcopy supplement is linked from the Instant Client page.  I haven't compared the set of DLLs that comprises to the set of DLLs you listed.

Answer (score 27):

You don't need to install any Oracle client separately.
I installed the following in the same directory as the .exe:

```
   Oracle.DataAccess.dll

   oci.dll 

   OraOps11w.dll

   oraociei11.dll

   msvcr71.dll
```

Make sure your project references the same Oracle.DataAccess.dll that you are delivering.
This worked on a fresh pc which had never had oracle clients installed.

I avoided using TNSNAMES.ora by specifiying a connection string like this

connectionstring =
  Data Source="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=))" +
  "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = )))"

If you are using TNSNAMES.ora just cut and paste the connection details into a single line string.

see 
   [What is the minimum client footprint required to connect C# to an Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602/what-is-the-minimum-client-footprint-required-to-connect-c-to-an-oracle-database)

for more information.

- ejm

For information on how to obtain the above dlls, see this tutorial: http://begeeben.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/accessing-oracle-database-without-installing-oracle-client/

Answer (score 13):

Since this question was posted, the Oracle Managed Client is now available (provided by Oracle). I have been using it with no problems. Does not require hunting for DLL's or special configuration. Just add the package, modify configuration file, and you're set. [NuGet Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) and [an article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-mar/o24odp-2147205.html) by Oracle about it..

Since this client is written entirely in .NET Managed code, it's architecture independent and there is no need for external DLL's, installing an Oracle Client, or anything like that.

You can install it in VS using Package Manager.

```
Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
```

I've taken to putting this in the machine.config file (though it'll also work in web.config or app.config). I've found that this helps avoid conflicts with other drivers that may be installed:

```
<configuration>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
          <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
          <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
          <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver"
               invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
               description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
               type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
      </system.data>
<configuration>
```

Then for your connection string:

```
 <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IPORNAMEOFHOST)(PORT=PORTNUM)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORACLESID)));User Id=ORACLEUSER;Password=ORACLEPASSWORD;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
```

- IPORNAMEOFHOST= This is the IP address or DNS name of your server.
- PORTNUM= This is the port number that Oracle is listening at. Typically 1521.
- ORACLESID= The SID of the database you're trying to connect to.
- ORACLEUSER= The username to use for the connection.
- ORACLEPASSWORD= The password to use for the connection.

Comment: Does this also work if you are targeting .NET 4 and using Entity Framework 5?

Comment: I can't speak as to EF5 with it, but I have successfully used it in .NET 4. [This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-mar/o24odp-2147205.html) suggests EF should work.

Answer (score 0):

For NET Framework   net462, net463, net47, net471, net472, net48
use the nuget package: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
In c# project, add the next line:

```
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" Version="21.5.0" />
```

For netcore .NET    net5.0/net6.0,netcoreapp3.0, netcoreapp3.1,netstandard2.1
use the package: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core

```
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.50" />
```

If you are using TNS names (e.g ORCL in tnsnames.ora), the connection string is:

```
 string oradb = $"Data Source=ORCL;User Id=hr;Password=hr;";
```

Also, you can use Easy Connect Naming Method;

```
 string oradb = $"Data Source=192.168.1.70/{SERVICE_NAME};User Id=hr;Password=hr;";
```