# Why does ODAC Connection.open() sometimes raise an OracleException?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, odac

I catch an exception with empty message just at `Connection.Open()` line.

the error code:-2147467259

the stack trace:

```
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
```

I say "sometimes" in my question because it really is sometimes. When I remove the **Oracle.DataAccess** reference and again I add it from the installation folder of ODP.net this problem disappeared for a while. But again I catch this awful exception without any clear reason for me.
What are the reasons behind this problem?

Comment: According to Alex Keh (Oracle Product Manager) [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2491412), the most common reason for `-2147467259` is "mismatch between Oracle.DataAccess.dll version and the unmanaged ODP.NET DLLs it's picking up from the PATH".  Try some of the suggestions in [this other StackOverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12460384/146325)

Comment: as I get from your reference to Alex Keh this problem happens when we installed different versions of ODP.Net but I should say ,I'm just using just 12c also I had deinsatall ODAC and install it again.

Comment: There seem to be lots of causes of this error but they all seem to some variety of installation issue.

Comment: tnx for your reply but in my case I think what causes this problem is not the installation issues (although this is prevalent reason) but I have some conjectures that I will share them when I'm sure.