# Application that will be connect through oracle 11g and 10g client

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I wrote a sample application in C# that connects to oracle database.
On my station I have installed Oracle Client 10g and in C# project I added reference to oracle.dataaccess.dll from oracle bin folder.
Everything is ok when I run app on desktops with oracle client in 10g version but on desktops with oracle client in 11g version, application doesn't work (crashing).
When I delete a reference and I add a reference to oracle.dataaccess.dll from 11g client, after building, app works only with oracle client 11g and crashes on workstations with oracle client 10g
How could I write an application that will work with 10g and 11g oracle clients?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this but to save me writing it all out, someone else has answered it in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407624/84539).

What I found was to take the required DLLs from 11g and it will connect to a 10g or 11g database.

Comment: Jon, thanks for answer, but I must provide only exe without dlls - on workstations we have oracle clients installed.