# Install OBDC driver for oracle database step-by-step

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I created an C# application which needs to connect to an oracle database and I want to use the OBDC connection to achieve this. The version of the database is *Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production*.

I read this post: 
[How can I deploy a .NET application that uses ODAC without installing the whole component to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935808/how-can-i-deploy-a-net-application-that-uses-odac-without-installing-the-whole)

I know that I do not need to install the oracle client but only the driver for OBDC. I spent much time searching for a step-by-step tutorial (which is up-to-date) on how to install and use the right drivers.

So here are my questions:

- What do I have to download from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html
- (Because I suppose xCode) How do I install the right components/drivers for a visual studio 2013 project
- Please give a short example code snippet which doesn't use tnsnames.ora

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @anbuj I tried it now and saw that the oracle database that can be selected there is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the ODBC principles: if you use ODBC, you don't have to do anything with oracle. The Oracle end-user db/interface will be hidden by ODBC. You will just provide the connection string (3 params: service, user, passwd)

If you want to use oracle with ODBC:

- From your link, download and install this one : **64-bit ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2) for Windows x64**
- Create a ODBC connection manually : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca6axakh.aspx and test it.
- Use this name in your c# project : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30xx126e.aspx

Comment: I installed the ODAC_xCopy (all components) as it is described in the readme.html. It seemed to work as the install directory was created as expected. I added the two directories oracle and oracle/bin to the system "Path" variable and made a restart. Unfortunately there wasn't any new driver which I could select in your second step. Drivers available are "SQL Server: SQLSRV32.DLL" and "SQL Server native client 11.0: SQLNCLI11.DLL"

Comment: Very curious. Try via Excel : "data / import external data / New database query / <New Data source>". Set a name and try to look for your oracle driver on the list.

Comment: There is a _Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle_ available. But when I type in the credentials and test the connection an error message appears: _Oracle Client- and Network connection were not found [..] You have to install the components_

Comment: Ok. The driver oracle should be named "Oracle 12g blabla" and should be last one of the list. I know Oracle client historically had problems with 64bits versions. May be you could try to install 1) the same package but 32-bits or 2) the instant client. This should not be necessary but it may work.

Comment: I installed the instant client (basic + odbc) and I see now the Oracle instant client driver in ODBC Data sources. But I cannot create a data source from this driver because it says that the file sqoras32.dll is missing in C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1 even though the file IS there?!

Comment: Add the place of dlls in the PATH variable (C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1 I guess).

Comment: I already had added the directory with the DLLs to the PATH variable. I controlled it again now: _C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1_ is the directory and _C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1;_ is at the beginning of PATH variable.

Comment: Do you have a ORACLE_HOME ver set up ?