# Include Oracle.DataAccess.dll in Visual Studio C# Project

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, dll

My project makes use of the *Oracle.DataAccess.dll* DLL and when I build and run my application it works fine on my PC, as I have added the reference in my project to it *C:\Oracle\instantclient_11_2_dc\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll*

However when I run on another machine without this reference it fails installation with the following message.

[image: unable to install or run the application]

How do I include the DLL file in my project so it is deployed with it as as requirement, and doesn't reference my local file system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deploy a .NET application that uses ODAC without installing the whole component to the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935808/how-can-i-deploy-a-net-application-that-uses-odac-without-installing-the-whole)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the Oracle client on the client machine if this is a client/server application.  If it is web based application then it should be installed there.

I don't use the instant client as I end up wanting to edit the connections in the TNSNames.ora so I use the full or Administrator install.
The client version will usually connect back or forward two Oracle versions but life is easier if you use the version appropriate to your database version.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to install the Oracle Data Access Components from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen on your dev machine AND any servers you plan on deploying to (or you can xcopy install per [How can I deploy a .NET application that uses ODAC without installing the whole component to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935808/how-can-i-deploy-a-net-application-that-uses-odac-without-installing-the-whole)).  Also marked Q as duplicate to this one.

Comment: Is this a requirement, I've seen other software just include the DLL when I browse their root directory in Program Files. They don't seem to install to the machine as such.

Comment: Check out this Q : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935808/how-can-i-deploy-a-net-application-that-uses-odac-without-installing-the-whole  I think you can use the instant client, but still need to xcopy the ODAC from above link,  Will update answer.