# Oracle.DataAccess.Client Dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, dll, odp.net

First of all, I want to use the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` to use `OracleBulkCopy`.

I want to know all the dlls that I need to be able to read from a database and then perform a bulkcopy in Oracle. Currently, we are using only one dll to perform all the reads from databases, we are using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`. But I can't use it to perform a bulkCopy.

I don't want to install ODP.NET for the users, I want to include the dll directly in the program. So I want to know the minimum required dlls to be able to use the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` in 32bit and in 64bit.

I know that there are some old post about this, but it's quiet old and the listed dlls are out of date. I can't event find some of them.

I installed the ODP.net for ODAC12 and I retreived all the listed dlls in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935808/how-can-i-deploy-a-net-application-that-uses-odac-without-installing-the-whole). I also tried with with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client). The listed dlls are pointing out the version 11.

I made a dummy project that opens a connection, reads a table and bulk it in another table. I copied the listed dlls from the posts in the root of the project and I included `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` in the project.

When I run my program in 64 bit I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'

When I run it in 32 bit, I get this error:

> Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

The dlls that I included are:

- oci.dll
- ociw32.dll
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll
- orannzsbb12.dll
- oraocci12.dll
- oraociei12.dll
- OraOps12.dll

Comment: Are you willing to pay money for a third party connector?  In other words, is this work for your employer who would be willing to shell out a few hundred bucks for some software, if you needed it?

Comment: What's the name of the third party connector?

Comment: Instead of trying to do this dll by dll which is fraught with problems, have a look at the "XCOPY" install. It is smaller and you can embed it into your own installation. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Comment: I've been using dotConnect for Oracle by DevArt since around 2009.  It does cost money, but it eliminates the dependencies for a local Oracle client (like Managed ODP) and still supports advanced OCI features like bulk inserts and updates.  And of course, it's all managed DLLs that can be GACed or localized.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I managed to make it work.

- Download the good version of the ODAC that will target your project.

1. For a [32bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html) project you need to download the ODAC12..._x32.zip (ODAC121021Xcopy_32bit.zip).
2. For the [64bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) project you need to download the ODAC12..._x64.zip

- Unzip it in an empty folder depending on the version you want (32bit vs 64bit).
- Locate in the `instantclient_12_1` folder all the dlls by searching *.dll in the windows search bar. You need to grab:

> 1. oci.dll
> 2. ociw32.dll
> 3. orannzsbb12.dll
> 4. oraociei12.dll
> 5. oraons.dll

- Locate in the `odp.net4` or `odp.net20` folder depending on your .NET version  this two dlls:

> 1. OraOps12.dll
> 2. Oracle.DataAccess.dll

- Copy the those 32bit dlls or 64bit dlls and put them directly in the Output path of your project. For example in `C:\...\vsProjects\BulkInsert\BulkInsert\bin\Debug`.
- Browse Oracle.DataAccess.dll in your project by pointing on the Output path.

[image: Solution Explorer Screenshot]

UPD: recent versions of the ODP.NET provider (downloaded from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdeploy-downloads.html)) have "19" suffix instead of "12" in their filenames:

> 1. oci.dll
> 2. ociw32.dll
> 3. orannzsbb19.dll
> 4. oraociei19.dll
> 5. oraons.dll
> 6. OraOps19.dll
> 7. Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Comment: I think it would be better to copy **all** files from folder `instantclient_12_1` (which is equal to install the Oracle Instance Client). I may work you your environment but on slightly different condition it may fail.

Comment: Watch you don't copy DLLs from the wrong version of bitness of Oracle. I did and got this error until I got all the DLLs from the same version of Oracle Instant Client: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589549/system-typeinitializationexception-the-type-initializer-for-oracle-dataaccess

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar problem; install oracle data access components (odac **ODTwithODAC122010.zip**) for solution.

Comment: Can you add a link to that said file?

Comment: [link](http://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/utilsoft-086879.html) 
you can select version on page

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not install the Oracle Instant client (or any other version of Oracle Client). This is a prerequisite for unmanaged ODP.NET provider.

Install the Oracle Instant client and you are fine. Otherwise you will get  nothing but trouble.