# unable to load OraOps12.dll when published to microsoft azure

Tags: c#, oracle, azure, dll, oracle12c

I'm currently building a simple website that accesses and displays the content of an Oracle database. Everything works when I run it locally, but as soon as I publish it to Azure I get an error saying "Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)". I've tried adding the dll to the project but to no avail.

I don't even have it as a reference in my project and it works locally, so any suggestions to get azure to find the dll, where I should put it, or an alternative way to access my oracle database would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: nope, just gave up in the end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle.DataAccess.Client Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509331/oracle-dataaccess-client-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey use this link to http://alderprogs.blogspot.com/2009/04/deploying-odpnet-with-oracle-instant.html. 
Firstly use the Xcopy version of the drivers downloaded from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html
add reference to Oracle.dataaccess.dll from this after which right click on it and select properties and in the properties set "local copy=true"

then what you have to do is right-click on the project select "Add Existing Item". Add all the required dlls like oci.dll,OraOps12.dll etc. Now in the properties of these of these dlls set "Copy to output directory = Copy if Newer" and publish to azure it will work.