# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException 0x80004005

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, iis

I have a .aspx page referencing Oracle.DataAccess. I'm able to launch the app through visual studio and it works well. My VS version is 2012, IIS is 7.5, OS is Win 7 and ODP is 3.5.

However, when I try to deploy it in IIS, it gives me an exception. I have tried the following so far: -

- Tried copying the DLLs as per - [How can I deploy a .NET application that uses ODAC without installing the whole component to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935808/how-can-i-deploy-a-net-application-that-uses-odac-without-installing-the-whole)
- Tried installing ODP 3.5, and then publishing it through visual studio.
- Tried editing the web.config and giving it the full connect string instead of just the DB alias: - (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= myhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=my_srv)))

I'm running out of ideas. Here's the code and the exception error. Please help: -

Code:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=MY_SRV;User Id=USERID;Password=PWD;";
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection conn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(oradb);
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand("myOracleStoredPrc", conn);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_db_name", "varchar2").Value = "abc";
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_name", "varchar2").Value = "xyz";
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Dispose();
```

Exception I get when I launch the iis site:

> Unhandled Execution Error 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: 
>   Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace: 
>   [OracleException (0x80004005)]
>      Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck) +1532
>      Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +49
>      Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +4800
>      WebApplication1.ResetOraclePwdForm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +72
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Comment: No inner exception? Is ODP deployed on your server? Why aren't you using the [Oracle Managed Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) which has no external dependencies?

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problems, but to specify the datatype of a parameter you should use the appropriate enumeration not a string. For Oracle you have to use OracleDbType.Varchar2

Comment: Thanks... Oracle Managed Driver solved the issue..!

Answer (score 0):

Moving to ManagedDataAccess solved the issue for me